# How do i fix accordion inside of resizeable block?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/jUHHU/4/) code works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#main').resizable({
            ghost: true,
            helper: 'border_accord'});

    /*$('#accord p').hide();

        $('#accord h3').toggle(function(){
            $(this).addClass('h3_click');
            $(this).next('p').slideDown().siblings('p:visible').slideUp();
            $(this).siblings('h3').removeClass('h3_click');}, 
                function(){
                    $(this).removeClass('h3_click').next('p').slideUp();
    });*/

    $('#accord').accordion({collapsible:true,active:false});

    $('button#yes').bind("click",function(){
    $( "#accord" ).accordion( "option", "disabled", true );

    });

    $('button#no').bind("click",function(){
    $( "#accord" ).accordion( "option", "disabled", false );

    });

        });

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">




</script>    

<style type="text/css">
*, html, body{
    padding:0px; margin:0px;}
#main{
    width:200px;
    min-height:200px;
    background-color:#e9e9e9;
    padding:10px;}
#header{
    height:22px;
    background-image:url(images/bg_header.png);
    border:1px solid #C90;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding-top:3px;}
#accord h3{
    height:25px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    background-image:url(images/bg_h3.png);
    margin-top:1px;
    margin-bottom:1px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#6699CC;
    padding-top:5px;
    cursor:pointer;}
#accord p{
    min-height:100px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    padding:10px;
    color:#333;}
#accord p span{
    display:block;
    margin-left:5px;
    margin-top:5px;}
.button_size{
    width:85px;
    height:25px;
    margin-top:5px;}
#accord h3:hover{
    background-image:url(images/hover.png);
    border:1px solid #FC6;
    color:#F96;}
#accord .h3_click{
    background-image:url(images/h3_cl.png);
    border-top:1px solid #FC6;
    border-right:1px solid #FC6;
    border-left:1px solid #FC6;
    color:#F96;}
.border_accord{
    border:1px dashed #999;}

</style>
<title>Ex</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="main">
     <h3 id="header" class="ui-widget-header">Resizable</h3>
     <div id="accord">
         <h3>Layer1</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada, ante at feugiat tincidunt, enim massa gravida metus, commodo lacinia massa diam vel eros. Proin eget urna. Nunc fringilla neque vitae odio. Vivamus vitae ligula.</p>
        <h3>Layer2</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada, ante at feugiat tincidunt, enim massa gravida metus, commodo lacinia massa diam vel eros. Proin eget urna. Nunc fringilla neque vitae odio. Vivamus vitae ligula.</p>
        <h3>Layer3</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Morbi malesuada, ante at feugiat tincidunt, enim massa gravida metus, commodo lacinia massa diam vel eros. Proin eget urna. Nunc fringilla neque vitae odio. Vivamus vitae ligula.</p>
        <h3>Layer4</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
           <span>&bull;&nbsp;Proin eget urna.</span>
           <span>&bull;&nbsp;Nunc fringilla neque vitae odio.</span>
           <span>&bull;&nbsp;Vivamus vitae ligula.</span>
        </p>
     </div>
     <button class="button_size" id="yes">F</button>
     <button class="button_size" id="no">A</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

​
```

But the problem is:

When i first resize the block, and then use accordion - accordion blocks fall out of resizeble block! :(  Why? How do i fix?

Answer (score 1):

jQuery UI resizeable is setting the element's height after a resize, hence the container's size is fixed and will not adapt to the accordion's height change.

You can use this to switch `height` to `min-height` so the container will grow with the accordion after being resized:

```
$('#main').bind('resizestart', function() {
    $(this).css('min-height', '0px');   
});

$('#main').bind('resizestop', function() {
    $(this).css({'min-height': $(this).css('height'), 'height': 'auto'});
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using resize event of resizable to call:

```
$('#accord').accordion('destroy').accordion(  options );
```